# how can i switch required element with selectOneRadio

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

i hava a register page and i need if i select item radio for example item one password required get true and if i select item two required get false

```
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="connection" value="#{UserBean.connection}" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="One"  />
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
                                    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

and i want something with this logic

```
    <c:if test="#{UserBean.connection =='One'}" >
                                    <p:password id="pwd" value="#{UserBean.pwd}" required="false"  />
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if>
                                <p:password id="pwd" value="#{UserBean.pwd}" required="true"  />
                                </c:if>
```

kind regards and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Do you want it visibly to be required before submission of the form (e.g. when the user changes the selectOneRadio) or only be validated at submission time of the form?

Comment: i want when i submit if have choosen item one i can register user without password and if i have choosen item two i must register user with a password i hope i explained well what i need

Comment: Yes, that I understood already but do you want e.g. the password to be visibly required (e.g. with a red star or a dot, see https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/outputLabel.xhtml) when the change in the selectOneRadio is made.

Comment: ah sorry, yes i want the password with a dot